# Difference between these 2 functions?

Tags: objective-c

I have 2 degree-to-radian functions pre-defined using `#define`:

Function 1:

```
#define degreesToRadians(degrees) (M_PI * degrees / 180.0)
```

Function 2:

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
```

Only the 2nd function returns correct answer, while the first one provides weird answer. What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non of the two "functions" mentioned above is a functions, they are macros, and the first macro is not safe, for example, expanding the macro `degreesToRadians(10 + 10)` gives `(M_PI * 10 + 10 / 180.0)`, which is interpreted as `((M_PI * 10) + (10 / 180.0))` and this is clearly wrong. While expanding `DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(10 + 10)` gives `((10 + 10 ) / 180.0 * M_PI)` which is correct.

The other difference is that `M_PI * degreess` might overflow the double boundaries, and thus give a wrong answer (but this requires a rather high value in `degrees`)

Comment: That _would_ be a high value of degrees :-) But it's not really a reason to choose one over the other. For example, a _small_ enough value of degrees in the second would result in `degrees / 180.0` becoming zero, a problem the first one won't have. I think it's probably enough just to suggest OP uses "sane" versions of angles :-)

Answer (score 2):

The *calculations* are pretty much identical, notwithstanding floating point limitations. However, you have `angle` surrounded with parentheses in the second macro, which is the *right* thing to do.

In the *first* macro, if you do:

```
x = degreesToRadians(a + 45);
```

then, remembering that macros are simple text substitutions, you'll end up with:

```
x = (M_PI * a + 45 / 180.0);
```

which will *not* end well, since it will be calculated as if you'd written:

```
x = (M_PI * a) + (45 / 180.0);
```

In other words, you simply multiply the angle by PI and add a constant `0.25`.

If instead you change the first one to be:

```
#define degreesToRadians(degrees) (M_PI * (degrees) / 180.0)
```

then it should begin to behave a little better.

---

The other difference has to do with either large or small values of the angle. A divide-then-multiply on a small angle (and I mean *really* small like `10-308`, approaching the IEEE754 limits) may result in a zero result while a multiply-then-divide on a *large* angle (like `10308`) may give you overflow.

My advice would be to ensure you use "normal" angles (or normalise them before conversion). Provided you do that, the different edge conditions of each method shouldn't matter.

---

And, in all honesty, you probably shouldn't even be *using* macros for this. With insanely optimising compilers and enumerations, macros should pretty much be relegated to conditional compilation nowadays. I'd simply rewrite it as a function along the lines of:

```
double degreesToRadians(double d) {
    return M_PI * d / 180.0;
}
```

Or, you could even adjust the code so as to *not* worry about small or large angles (if you're paranoid):

```
double degreesToRadians(double d) {
    if ((d > -1) && (d < 1))
        return (M_PI * d) / 180.0;
    return (d / 180.0) * M_PI;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I overlook this behavior of obj-c macro.